# REST Call from Selenium with session ID is invalid

Tags: selenium

I am trying to make REST call with Apache's HTTPClient. I would like to update a record after a selenium Test.

```
Cookie sessionId = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sid");
PostMethod request = new PostMethod(url){
    @Override public String getName() { return "PATCH"; }
};
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + sessionId.getValue());

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.executeMethod(request);
String respBody = request.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

respBody: {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure that a session initiated from a browser can be shared; interesting question. Why do you need to reuse the session?

Comment: I use Selenium, so I actually log in on the page with my credentials. I want to re-use it, because I dont want to authenticate (again) via REST. It said somewhere in the documentation that the sessionID can be used as token. I actually manged to make a POST request with Chrome Postman (REST Addon). So it works, it is just some issue with my Java code I assume.

Comment: @Miller It's "Bearer " not "OAuth ". See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header is incorrect. It should be set as follows:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+sessionId.getValue());
```

There's no issue sharing a browser session ID with REST or even SOAP API.

### Update

Here's the code I used to test out the configuration:

```
  @Test
  public void testCase() throws Exception {
    // Do some stuff in salesforce.com
    Cookie c = driver.manage().getCookieNamed("sid");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(baseUrl+"services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Account/0015000000osa4j") {
        @Override public String getName() { return "PATCH"; }
    };
    method.setRequestEntity(new RequestEntity() {

        @Override
        public void writeRequest(OutputStream arg0) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.write("{ \"BillingCity\": \"San Mateo\"}".getBytes());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRepeatable() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String getContentType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "application/json";
        }

        @Override
        public long getContentLength() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "{ \"BillingCity\": \"San Mateo\"}".length();
        }
    });
    method.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth "+c.getValue());
    client.executeMethod(method);
    System.out.println(method.getStatusCode());
```

Try using my code verbatim with a valid account ID (or other object). It works when I tried it, so there shouldn't be a problem. Also check to make sure that SID isn't null or empty for some reason. I'm using the Firefox driver, by the way.

Comment: I am sorry, but that did not solve the issue. See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_update_fields.htm it actually says OAuth, but Bearer did not work either :(

Comment: Testing Selenium now... Be right back with you.

Comment: Sorry, which HttpClient are you using? I can't seem to find PostMethod at all, so I'm apparently missing a lib.

Comment: commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1

Comment: It's working for me. Check my code, compare it to your own.

Comment: What exactly was wrong?

Comment: Well first of all, my code got very messy, so your example got me down to the important basics to make it work. The problem i encountered was that I was trying to use an authentication token from one instance on another one. So I had to receive the salesforce environment with the token to send requests to the correct instance. Now I receive a Salesforce internal server error, when I want to upload a picture via chatter - but that is some other issue ;)